# LocalStack Kinesis Lambda sets StartingPosition to LATEST no matter what

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis, localstack

I have a simple localstack pipeline:

- Kinesis with a single shard
- Single lambda function reading the data

When setting the lambda function event_source_mapping the StartingPosition is always being set to **LATEST** regardless of what was input.
I have tried with awscli and boto3 with the same results. Am I doing something incorrectly?

No matter what I put in the --starting-position argument it always returns with LATEST selected.

I have tried with awscli and boto3 with the same results.
Am I doing something incorrectly?

**Example awscli code:**

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda create-event-source-mapping --function-name lambda_2_db --event-source arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:000000000000:stream/polling_single_shard --batch-size 100 --starting-position TRIM_HORIZON
```

**Console output:**

**[image: strong text]**